# Swift 3 selector usage

Tags: swift3

I have this code while converting from old version of Swift o version 3...

```
func ownCatalogBackButton() {
  // ...
}
```

And elsewhere in the same class I have

```
outletScoresDetailsNav.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.ownCatalogBackButton(_:)));
```

but I get error

> Value of type 'ViewControllerScoresDetails' has no member
>   ownCatalogBackButton

Just in case I misunderstood the selector syntax for a function without any parameters I have also tried:

```
outletScoresDetailsNav.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.ownCatalogBackButton()));

outletScoresDetailsNav.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.ownCatalogBackButton(:)));

outletScoresDetailsNav.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.ownCatalogBackButton(_)));
```

My brain must be fried after fixing the first 1500 issues when converting... What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
outletScoresDetailsNav.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.ownCatalogBackButton));
```